# can't boot after reboot when upgrade to 20.04 was done

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade

I can't boot after reboot when upgrade to 20.04 was done.
I get stuck on mysql start loop

```
starting MYSQL Community Server...
[FAILED] Failed to stat MYSQL Communoity Server.
See 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details
[OK] Stopped MYSQL Community Server.
starting MYSQL Community Server...
[FAILED] Failed to stat MYSQL Communoity Server.
See 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details
[OK] Stopped MYSQL Community Server.
...
```

and I can't get boot menu to use my bootable usb drive when i try (hard) boot it.
I tried holding down F2 or F12 even escap button no luck.
How do I get access to the boot please?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check `systemctl status mysql.service` for details, as suggested in line 3 of the error output ?

Comment: How do I do that? that message loop does not stop :(

Comment: Go to a console by typing 'ctrl-ALT-F3` , log in and run the command ... you get back to "the normal screen" by pressing `CTRl-ALT-F2` .

Comment: I just get a blinking cursor

Comment: Hit `Enter` to get a `login: ` prompt.

Comment: that doesn't do nothing :(.

Comment: any other way to get to recovery mode ?